# MySQL Join three tables, two of them with additional condition

Tags: mysql, join

I have to left join one table (bonds) with two other tables (orders_bid, orders_ask). But both other tables must also have a condition between them (customer_id must be the same).

```
bonds
-----------
id
ticker
```

...

```
orders_bid
-----------
id
bonds_id
customer_id
price
```

...

```
orders_ask
-----------
id
bonds_id 
customer_id 
price
```

My approach is the following:

```
SELECT bonds.ticker, orders_bid.price, orders_ask.price FROM bonds
LEFT JOIN orders_bid ON bonds.id=orders_bid.bonds_id
LEFT JOIN orders_ask ON bonds.id=orders_ask.bonds_id
```

But this leads to result rows are getting mixed over different customers, as the customer_id is not respected between both joined tables. Something like...

```
WHERE orders_bid.customer_id=orders_aks.customer_id
```

...is additionally needed, but it must not be a WHERE statement as something like an outer join is needed (one side might be empty). What's the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by adding it to the JOIN conditions.

```
SELECT    bonds.ticker, orders_bid.price, orders_ask.price FROM bonds
LEFT JOIN orders_bid 
ON        bonds.id = orders_bid.bonds_id
LEFT JOIN orders_ask 
ON        bonds.id = orders_ask.bonds_id
AND       orders_bid.customer_id = orders_ask.customer_id
```

Comment: I'll try. But won't this only affect the second join?

Comment: those that have customer_id field